# Pass a function to another function in c# to call on a given model

Tags: c#, generics, delegates

I have this incomplete and broken example here and I wanted to know if it is possible to pass a function to another function that takes the Model and properties into account? please see the comments in the example below for what I mean.

```
private void ValidateSurvey(Survey survey)
{
    // lines 1 to 10, or 1 to 8 or 11 to 16, etc
    for (var i = survey.FirstLine; i <= survey.LastLine; i++)
    {
        IsAnswerValid(survey, "1.1.1", i, /* some rules to apply here i.e. [TModel] != null && [TModel].Value == "foo" */ ) 
    }

}

private bool IsAnswerValid<TAnswer>(
    Survey survey,
    string rowName, 
    int lineNumber,
    Func<TAnswer, bool> answerValueValidator 
) where TAnswer : Answer
{
    if (survey == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("survey");
    if (answerValueValidator == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("answerValueValidator");
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(rowName))
        throw new ArgumentNullException("Null/blank rowName specified");
    if(lineNumber < 0)
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("lineNumber must be positive");

    // get answer list for the required row
    var answerList = survey.Rows
        .Where(
            r => r.Name.Trim().ToLower() == rowName.Trim().ToLower() && r.Answers != null
        ).SelectMany(a => a.Answers);

    // get the first relevant answer for the line number specified
    var answer = answerList.FirstOrDefault(a => a.LineNumber == lineNumber);

    return answerValueValidator(answer);

    //return (answer != null && answer.Value);
}
```

**UPDATE: to show lambda use and removal of generics based on the answers, works now sorry for just confusing myself over a syntax error causing intellisense not to appear, hopefully someone might find this useful**

```
private void ValidateSurvey(Survey survey)
{
    // lines 1 to 10, or 1 to 8 or 11 to 16, etc
    for (var i = survey.FirstLine; i <= survey.LastLine; i++)
    {
        IsAnswerValid(survey, "1.1.1", i, a => a != null && a.Value = "foo" ) 
    }

}

private bool IsAnswerValid(
    Survey survey,
    string rowName, 
    int lineNumber,
    Func<Answer, bool> answerValueValidator 
)
{
    if (survey == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("survey");
    if (answerValueValidator == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("answerValueValidator");
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(rowName))
        throw new ArgumentNullException("Null/blank rowName specified");
    if(lineNumber < 0)
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("lineNumber must be positive");

    // get answer list for the required row
    var answerList = survey.Rows
        .Where(
            r => r.Name.Trim().ToLower() == rowName.Trim().ToLower() && r.Answers != null
        ).SelectMany(a => a.Answers);

    // get the first relevant answer for the line number specified
    var answer = answerList.FirstOrDefault(a => a.LineNumber == lineNumber);

    return answerValueValidator(answer);
}
```

Comment: That probably shouldn't be generic.

Comment: @SLaks Yup. I took another look and the use of generics is not required, that was just me getting confused again. Thanks

Comment: `String.Equals(x, y. SrtingComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for lambda expressions:

```
IsAnswerValid<Answer>(survey, "1.1.1", i, a => a.Something || a.SomethingElse);
```

Comment: Believe it or not I tried using a lambda right before I posted and the IntelliSense wasn't picking up on the properties.. but obviously its getting late and I have since slightly adjusted the code and its working :-( for some reason I thought this didn't like my Type but its working now. thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think you're already close to what you want - try changing this:

```
// get the first relevant answer for the line number specified
var answer = answerList.FirstOrDefault(a => a.LineNumber == lineNumber);
```

To this:

```
// get the first relevant answer for the line number specified
var answer = answerList
    .OfType<TAnswer>()
    .FirstOrDefault(a => a.LineNumber == lineNumber);
```

Which you can then pass in any `Answer -> bool` lambda:

```
IsAnswerValid<Answer>(survey, "1.1.1", i, ans => ans.LineNumber == 1);
```